# Best way to join the two tables *including* duplicates from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, group-by, cross-apply

Accounts (table)

```
+----+----------+----------+-------+
| id | account# | supplier | RepID |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | 123xyz   | Boston   |     2 |
|  2 | 245xyz   | Chicago  |     2 |
|  3 | 425xyz   | Chicago  |     3 |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
```

PayOut (table)

```
+----+----------+----------+-------------+--------+
| id | account# | supplier | datecreated | Amount |
+----+----------+----------+-------------+--------+
|  5 | 245xyz   | Chicago  | 01-15-2009  | 25     |
|  6 | 123xyz   | Boston   | 10-15-2011  | 50     |
|  7 | 123xyz   | Boston   | 10-15-2011  | -50    |
|  8 | 123xyz   | Boston   | 10-15-2011  | 50     |
|  9 | 425xyz   | Chicago  | 10-15-2011  | 100    |
+----+----------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

I have accounts table and I have payout table. Payout table comes from abroad so we do not have any control over it. This leaves us with a problem that we can't join the two tables based on record ID field, that is one problem which we can't solved. We therefore join based on Account#, SupplierID (2nd and 3rd column). This creates a problem that it creates (possibly) many to many relationship. But we filter our records if they are active and we use a second filter on payout table when the payout was created. Payout are created months to month. There are two problems with this in my view

1. The query takes quite a bit of time to complete (could be inefficient)
2. There are certain duplicates that are removed which should not be removed. Example is record 6 and 8 in payout table. What happened here is, we got a customer, then the customer cancelled then he got him back. In this case +50, -50 and +50. Again all values are valid and must show in the report for audit purposes. Currently only one +50 is shown, the other is lost. There are a couple of other problems within the report that comes once in a while.

Here is the query. It uses groups by to remove duplicates. I would like to have an advance query which outperforms and which does takes into account that no record in PayOut table is duplicated as long as they come up in the month of the report.

Here is our current query

```
/* Supplied  to Store Procedure */
-----------------------------------
@RepID // the person for whome payout is calculated
@Month // of payment date
@year  // year of payment date
-----------------------------------
select distinct 
A.col1, 
A.col2,
...
A.col10, 
B.col2, 
B.Col2, 
B.Amount /* this is the important column, portion of which goes to Rep */
from records A
JOIN payout B 
on A.Supplier = B.Supplier AND A.Account# = B.Account#
where datepart(mm, B.datecreated) = @Month /* parameter to stored procedure */
  and datepart(yyyy, B.datecreated) = @Year
  and A.[rep ID] = @RepID /* parameter to SP */
group by
col1,col2,col3,....col10
order by customerName
```

Is this query optimum? Can I improve it using CROSS APPLY or WHERE EXISTs that will make it faster as well as remove the duplicate problem?

Note that this query is used to get payout of a rep. Hence every record has repid field who it is assigned to. Ideally I would like to use Select WHERE Exist query.

Comment: Can you show your actual fields in the select?  It's relevant to know which fields get taken from which table.

Comment: And what is it you actually want?  You say you have a 'duplicates' problem, but seem to be wanting _more_ rows (7 & 8).  It would be helpful to have current/desired result sets.

Comment: I have duplicates removed problem. They are removed but they should be there. I am afraid I can't post the actual query. My query is very similar to the actual one except in the actual query there is MAX(col1 case statement) used and I have found that is unnesssary. And that leads to using 10 group by statements. I want an expert opinion if this a sound query how to improve/fix it.

Comment: Instead of using datepart(mm, B.datecreated) = Month and datepart(yyyy, B.datecreated) = Year, you can use month(B.datecreated) = Month and year(B.datecreated) = Year. I don't understand your example of records 6 and 8 where the Account#'s are different in the Payout table but the supplier is the same. Whereas in the Accounts table, those two Account#'s have different suppliers. How can you use those two columns to join if your data is inconsistent. This could be the cause of your missing duplicates. Sorry I can't add ampersands in front of variables.

Comment: @Yung that is a good tip if it will improve performance a bit. I created the test case on the fly so there could be some errors. Now I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you want because in one place you say you 'want' the duplicates but then you say that you are using the group by to remove duplicates.  So the first thought would be "Why not just get rid of the group by?".  But I have to believe you are smart enough to have thought of that yourself, so I assume it's got to be there for a reason.

I think someone here could help you pretty easily if you could post the actual query, but since you say you can't I will just try to give you some direction in solving the problem...

Instead of trying to do everything in one statement, use temporary tables or views to split it up.  It may be easier for you to think about how to get rid of the duplicates you don't want and keep the ones you do first and put those into a temporary table, and then join the tables together and work with that.

Comment: The previous programmer used group by and distinct to remove duplicates. We found that certain duplicates need to be there as I have stated in the Question. I have rewritten the query using CROSS APPLY. I am still troubleshooting and comparing the result with the original. I dont think it is common practice to post the actual query or may be If I can change a lot of stuff in it. If I can't work it out, I may well post it. My other part of the question was, is this query sound. Can it be better written with performance improvment.

Comment: Whether it's sound or not is somewhat of a subjective question.  My approach is to try not to have expressions compensating for bad data in my top level query.  That means I may have a query or a view that filters/transforms the data how it 'ought' to be first, and then I query on that data.